# WPF - grid with opacity and shadow

Tags: .net, wpf

i would like to create grid with white opacity background and with outer shadow. My code created grid with white background and shadow, but without opacity:

```
<Border Margin="20" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4"
    Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrush}">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#fff" Opacity="0.5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

How to creategrid with white opacity background and outer shadow?
Thanks for advice.

Comment: ControlLightLightBrush is almost white. White grid with white cover? Not much difference if semi-transparent on not. choose another border background and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the word `white` instead of `#fff` for the background color. I don't think that is a well formed RGB value.